# Should I use Padé approximation for time delay at a transfer function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

If I want to do a bode plot of a transfer function who looks like this : $$ G (s) = \frac {Ke^{-Ts}}{s^2 + 2s + 3} $$

Should I just compute the bode plot by replacing $s $ to $j\omega $ and then find the amplitude and phase. When it comes to delay, only the phase will be effected.

Or should I replace $e^{-Ts} $ with Padé approximation? 
Or should I transform the transfer function to discrete transfer function?

Comment: In MATLAB you can specify it with [input or output delay](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/time-delays-in-linear-systems.html).

Comment: Yes. I Know but I not using MATLAB. I use octave.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici This question is tailored for you...

Comment: You are asking if you should use the Padé approximation, but it is not clear what your goal is. Depending on your goal this might be a good or bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Padé approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PadeApproximant.html) or discretize the system when dealing with delay. However both these methods will always be an approximation of the actual transfer function, so at sufficiently high frequencies they will always start to diverge significantly. But if you choose a Padé approximation of high enough order or discretize the system with a small enough sample time then the frequencies at which this happens can get arbitrarily high.

The advantage of Padé is that the magnitude does not get distorted, however the phase does. Discretizing a system distorts both, but the phase distortion is typically less, however it is only really defined up until the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency). For comparison take a look at the figure below, which plots the Bode diagram of your given transfer function with $K=1$ and $T=1$.

[image: Bode diagram]

If you want an exact representation of your transfer function then the only option would be to evaluate it manually. So calculate the magnitude and phase for the desired frequencies ($s=j\,\omega$). The only downside to this is phase wrapping (from a single complex number the phase will always be in a range of 360° or 2$\pi$). You can try to correct this by detecting which multiple of a full rotation would yields the smallest phase jump compared to the previous phase. However this has the downside that this does not work when you have poles and zeros very close to the imaginary axis, for example

$$
G(s) = \frac{1}{(s^2 + 1)^2},
$$

has a jump of -360° in its actual phase. So an advantage of the previous two methods would be that you probably still can use the build-in function of Octave to plot the Bode diagram and not have to deal with phase wrapping, however I am not sure if they would be able to handle jumps of 360°.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I tried to compute a TF with delay numericaly. But the phase did look like a sharp shark tooth. That's the reason I asking this question.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson That is because it gets wrapped (atan2, or whatever function you are using will always return a phase in the region of +180° and -180° (or +π and -π when using radians). You could fix this by trying to detect these jumps by adding a multiple of 360° (or 2π) such that the jump relative to the previous phase is the smallest. These jumps do not affect the Nyquist diagram by the way. The only downside of this is that it can make a mistake when poles or zeros are located close to the imagery axis.

Comment: Ok. I think that Padé approximation will do the job for me.